# Basic Lisp Macro error

Tags: common-lisp

Little help here please . I am trying to create this lisp macro which takes a list (of numbers) as input and returns the sum of those numbers. The code

```
(setf g (list 1 2 3 4))

(defmacro add-test(var)
    `(+ ,@var))
```

`(add-test g)` gives this error

```
The value G is not of type LIST.
[Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

At the same time `(add-test (1 2 3 4))` gives the correct result which is 10.

Can you please explain , why is it not working when variable is passed in to the function?

Other details -

Lispbox - SBCL

Ubuntu Linux

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's easy and one of the most common macro questions.

```
(add-test g)
```

Now on macro expansion, the macro `ADD-TEST` is called with the parameter `VAR` getting the value `G`, a symbol.

Then you try a list operation. The backquote expression

```
`(+ ,@var)
```

The value of `VAR` is `G`, and you try to splice that into the list `(+ ... )`. Now the returned expression is `(+ . G)`.

```
CL-USER 12 > (macroexpand '(add-test g))
(+ . G)
T
```

`(+ . G)` is not a valid Lisp form. It's not valid source code.

Remember, the parameters to a Macro are the unevaluated source expressions.

Compare that with the following:

```
CL-USER 13 > (macroexpand '(add-test (1 2 3 4)))
(+ 1 2 3 4)
T
```

You said: 'Can you please explain, why is it not working when variable is passed in to the function?'

Remember, `ADD-TEST` is NOT a function, it is a macro. A macro gets the source code passed and returns a new form - that form is then later evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Rainer for the detailed answer. That helped a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, let's say we take bdev's idea further. Suppose I have some sort of optimizable expression (a list of integers!), and I want to optimize the expression prior to "run-time". How would I do that? (although I suppose (eval G) might work...).

Comment: @Paul Nathan: you can EVAL it, COMPILE it, FUNCALL it, APPLY it - there are almost no limits. See also DEFINE-COMPILER-MACRO, which allows you to write optimizations.

Comment: @Rainer - I finally found the solution for this -
(defmacro add-test(x)    `(+,@(evalx))) 
                                                                
Thanks again for explaining this.

Comment: @Paul - Thanks for the 'eval' tip.

Comment: @bdev, eval also works only for some cases, btw. Can you imagine where EVAL does not help?

Comment: @Rainer - I am not sure. But I think 'eval' can not be used inside an ordinary function as the function evaluates it's arguments automatically. Thanks.