# Strange macroexpansion error in SBCL

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quote

I want to write a Fibonacci number computing function `fib` in Lisp using SBCL 1.3.3 for Windows x86_64. Use lazy computation to avoid repetition. The working code so far is:

```
(defvar *fibs* (make-hash-table))

(defun get-value (idx)
  (if (functionp (gethash idx *fibs*))
    (setf (gethash idx *fibs*)
      (funcall (gethash idx *fibs*)))
    (gethash idx *fibs*)))

(defun fib (n)
  (loop for i from 0 below n
    if (< i 2) do (setf (gethash i *fibs*) 1)
    else do (setf (gethash i *fibs*)
      (eval `(lambda () (+ (get-value ,(- i 2))
                           (get-value ,(- i 1)))))))
  (get-value (- n 1)))
```

Now, I don't want to call `eval` inside `fib`, so I introduce the macros here:

```
(defvar *fibs* (make-hash-table))

(defun get-value (idx)
  (if (functionp (gethash idx *fibs*))
    (setf (gethash idx *fibs*)
      (funcall (gethash idx *fibs*)))
    (gethash idx *fibs*)))

(defmacro code-for (idx)
  `(lambda () (+ (get-value ,(- idx 2))
                 (get-value ,(- idx 1)))))

(defun fib (n)
  (loop for i from 0 below n
    if (< i 2) do (setf (gethash i *fibs*) 1)
    else do (setf (gethash i *fibs*) (code-for i)))
  (get-value (- n 1)))
```

But it says:

```
; in: DEFUN FIB
;     (CODE-FOR I)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (CODE-FOR I). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
;   
;    Argument X is not a NUMBER: I
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
```

It is very strange: I have no argument `X` in code and `I` is always used as integer.

After some research, I found that there is macroexpansion of `code-for` inside a macros `loop`, and that `code-for` received `i` as symbol (?) rather than as a number, and that is the complain. Still, I have no idea of why the code is wrong, or how to improve it.

Edit 12.04.2018.

As pointed by tfb, the best approach to the problem depends on what the problem is. And the whole issue was to explain to students what is lazy evaluation, how it can be done in Lisp and why it may be necessary. The Fibonacci numbers is not the main goal of this example.

coredump showed the root cause of the issue (macroexpansion) and the solution to it (extra binding for i). Unfortunately, this made all the code not appropriate for showcase, because of too many extra explanations. So I end up by changing the `loop` by recursion:

```
(defvar *fibs* (make-hash-table))

(defun get-value (idx)
  (if (functionp (gethash idx *fibs*))
    (setf (gethash idx *fibs*)
      (funcall (gethash idx *fibs*)))
    (gethash idx *fibs*)))

(defun fib (n &optional (i (- n 1)))
  (if (< i 2) (setf (gethash i *fibs*) 1)
    (setf (gethash i *fibs*)
      (lambda () (+ (get-value (- i 2))
                    (get-value (- i 1))))))
  (if (zerop i) (get-value (- n 1))
    (fib n (- i 1))))
```

Comment: If this is trying to explain lazy evaluation then it's not a great example, because it mixes up lazy evaluation and memoization, which are not the same thing at all: if you write a `fib` function in a lazy language naively it has the same terrible performance that it does in an eager language.

Comment: the macro problem is the same as for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755280/basic-lisp-macro-question

Comment: The performance of lazy version of `fib` is better than eager version of it. In eager version `(+ (fib (- n 2)) (fib (- n 1)))` the complexity is exponential due to two recursive calls to `fib`. In lazy version `(+ (get-value (- n 2)) (get-value (- n 1)))` the complexity is linear because only the first call to `get-value` actually computes something, the second uses already computed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why your macro fails

Here is what `code-for` sees:

```
(code-for i)
```

The first argument is the symbol `i`. However, you are trying to perform arithmetic with this symbol during macroexpansion. This fails.

> Now, I don't want to call eval inside fib, so I introduce the macros

This is generally a wrong use for macros. All the macro manipulates is code, and has no way to know what a *runtime* value will be equal to.

### Neither `eval` nor a macro are necessary

You can build a closure easily:

```
(lambda () (+ (get-value (- i 2))
              (get-value (- i 1))))
```

The only problem you will have here is that `i`, which the lambda closes over, is being mutated by the loop. When you eventually call the closure, its value will be different. You have to establish a fresh binding:

```
(let ((i i)) (lambda ...))
```

Comment: Thank you @coredump. Of course I used `lambda` without macros and `eval` at all, but this also fails, it infinitely calls `get-value`. So the problem is extra binding `(let ((i i)) (lambda ...))`.

Answer (score 3):

[Note the answer by coredump gives an explanation of what is wrong with your macro: I have focused on what is wrong with the function and a better approach to the problem instead.]

I am not sure why you think you need `EVAL` here, or macros: you can just make a function with `LAMBDA`.  Here is a version of your code which works:

```
(defvar *fibs* (make-hash-table))

(defun get-value (idx &optional (default nil))
  ;; return the value and whether it was there.  If it's a function,
  ;; call it and stash the result
  (multiple-value-bind (got presentp)
      (gethash idx *fibs* default)
    (values
     (typecase got
       (function (setf (gethash idx *fibs*)
                       (funcall got)))
       (t got))
     presentp)))

(defun fib (n)
  (loop for i from 0 below n
        if (< i 2) do (setf (gethash i *fibs*) 1)
        else do (setf (gethash i *fibs*)
                      (let ((i i))
                        ;; rebind I as we don't want to depend on whatever
                        ;; LOOP does, which probably is mutate a single
                        ;; binding of I
                        (lambda () (+ (get-value (- i 2))
                                      (get-value (- i 1)))))))
  ;; just return the first value as we know the second will be T, and
  ;; it's not interesting
  (values (get-value (- n 1))))
```

But this is a fairly grotty approach.  Instead, you can just use an explicitly-memoized function like the below:

```
(defun fibonacci (n)
  ;; an explicitly-memoized version of the Fibonacci function
  (let ((memo (make-hash-table :test #'eql)))
    (labels ((fib (m)
               (cond
                ((< m 1)
                 (error "defined on naturals (excluding 0)"))
                ((< m 3)
                 1)
                (t
                 (multiple-value-bind (v p) (gethash m memo)
                   (if p
                       v
                     (setf (gethash m memo) (+ (fib (- m 1))
                                                (fib (- m 2))))))))))
      (fib n))))
```

Better yet, define a macro which lets you memoize any function: there are packages out there which let you do this, although I'm not sure what they are (one is due to me, but I am not sure that there are not better ones, or in fact the right place to find my one now!)